# Pragmatically set Button in Right Side in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, button

I was Creating Button Programatically using Linear Layout. But I Can't Change Logout Button Alignment to Right Side.

[image]

Thanks in Advance...

My Code is

```
lView = new LinearLayout(Main2Activity.this);
                   // lView.setPadding(0,150,0,0);
                    lView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#EDFCFC"));
                    lView.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));

                    Button logout = new Button(Main2Activity.this);
                    logout.setText("Logout");
                    logout.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);

                    logout.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#F53F37"));
                    lView.addView(logout);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `setGravity` that you are using is for the text inside the `button`. 
In order to set the `gravity` of the entire `button` you need to work with the `layoutParams`. Please try the below code:

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams( LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
params.gravity = Gravity.CENTER; 
logout.setLayoutParams(params);
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
 RelativeLayout rl = new RelativeLayout(Main2Activity.this);
Button logout = new Button(Main2Activity.this);
logout.setText("Hello, World");

RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams
        (LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT);
logout.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#F53F37"));
rl.addView(logout, lp);
```

Comment: He is using a linear layout, your code won't work with him!

Answer (score 0):

you can try in your xml file to put in the Button the code :

```
android:layout_marginLeft="how much dp you want"
```

or try :

```
android:layout_gravity="right"
```